# How to Call "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" method again with in same "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" method

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I need to call didSelectRowAtIndexPath method in UITableView again within inside the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

The code is as follows:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
          ------ --- ----
          ------ --- ----
          ------ --- ----
          ------ --- ----

    [tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:1];
}
```

If I used code as before, it is not accepted.

Is there any possible way to call "`didSelectRowAtIndexPath`" method inside same "`didSelectRowAtIndexPath`" method?

Comment: Why do you need to call it again? This is not best practice.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you meant to call your delegate rather than then table.

```
[self tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```